# Как правильно прописать интерфейс

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
PIXI.Point.prototype.Multiply = function (value: number) {
    this.x *= value;
    this.y *= value;
    return this;
};

const test = new PIXI.Point(1, 1);
console.log(test.Multiply(2));
```

Typescript ругается:

> TS2339: Property 'Multiply' does not exist on type 'Point'.

Пробовал по другому тоже самое:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: надо идти туда где описан `Point`

Comment: либо забить на типы и привести все к any

Comment: не забить на типы не вариант, нужно как то правильно описать интерфейс

Comment: @Grundy этот вариант как то работает https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16813118/extending-object-prototype-with-typescript но как я не крутил у меня не выходит повторить с PIXI.Point

Comment: _Пробовал по другому тоже самое:_ - код должен быть кодом, а не картинкой.

Answer (score 1):

То, что вы пытаетесь сделать называется `augmentation` (расширение) и для классов это не поддерживается (и не будет поддерживаться). На эту тему было открыто большое количество issues еще с 1.x версий TypeScript, команда Microsoft отказалась интегрировать в компилятор возможность `class augmentation`, объяснив это тем, что мы не должны мутировать существующий прототип, а расширить его, наследуясь от него, поэтому функция `parseAmbientExternalModuleDeclaration` из компилятора позволяет расширять только интерфейсы. Это проблема тех библиотек, которые вместо интерфейсов используют классы.

Используя `any` вы теряете возможность статического анализа, но вариант, который вы привели на скриншоте является правильным:

```
class Point extends PIXI.Point { ... }

const test = new PIXI.Point(1, 2);
```

Только тут непонятно зачем вы создаете инстанс класса `Point` из пространства имен `PIXI`, используйте свой класс:

```
class Point extends PIXI.Point {
    public multiply() ....
}

const test = new Point();
console.log(test.multiply());
```

**UPD:**

Если вам все же чревато делать то, что вы пытаетесь сделать - мутировать прототип и тд, то можем прибегнуть к такому грязному хаку. Создаем папку `fixed_declarations` куда копируем `index.d.ts` из `node_modules/@types/pixi.js`. В этом же файле добавляем метод классу:

```
class Point extends PointLike {
    constructor(x?: number, y?: number);
    clone(): Point;
    equals(p: PointLike): boolean;
    multiply?(value: number): number;
}
```

После всего ставим пакеты `cpy` и `cpy-cli`:

```
yarn add -D cpy cpy-cli
```

В `package.json` в секцию `scripts` добавляем новые задачи:

```
"scripts": {
    "cpy": "cpy",
    "fix:pixi": "cpy ./fixed_declarations/index.d.ts ./node_modules/@types/pixi.js --rename=index.d.ts"
}
```

У вас должны быть задачи для билдов, вы просто выполняете эту задачу перед билдами `"build": "yarn fix:pixi && webpack -p"` (как пример).